# Golang OpenGL line being drawn on Linux but not on Windows10

Tags: go, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am using the same OpenGL code written in Golang to draw two lines in a 640x480 pixel space. I am puzzled because both lines are drawn correctly in Linux, but only one of them is drawn in Windows10. What could cause that difference in OpenGL behavior?

- Line 1: 0,0 - 639,479 (works only on Linux)
- Line 2: 50,0 - 0,50   (works on both Linux and Windows10)

On Linux, both Lines are drawn correctly:

[image: linux screenshot]

App logs from Linux:

```
2019/08/15 02:44:12 requesting window for OpenGL 3.3
2019/08/15 02:44:12 graphicsStart(9): 640 x 480
2019/08/15 02:44:12 OpenGL version 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8
2019/08/15 02:44:12 OpenGL program: 3
2019/08/15 02:44:12 pixelToClip: 0 x 0 => -1.000000 x 1.000000
2019/08/15 02:44:12 pixelToClip: 639 x 479 => 1.000000 x -1.000000
2019/08/15 02:44:12 pixelToClip: 50 x 0 => -0.843506 x 1.000000
2019/08/15 02:44:12 pixelToClip: 0 x 50 => -1.000000 x 0.791232
```

On Windows10, only the second line is drawn:

[image: windows10 screenshot]

App logs from Windows10:

```
2019/08/15 18:41:19 requesting window for OpenGL 3.3
2019/08/15 18:41:19 graphicsStart(9): 640 x 480
2019/08/15 18:41:19 OpenGL version 3.3.0 - Build 21.20.16.4627
2019/08/15 18:41:19 OpenGL program: 3
2019/08/15 18:41:19 pixelToClip: 0 x 0 => -1.000000 x 1.000000
2019/08/15 18:41:19 pixelToClip: 639 x 479 => 1.000000 x -1.000000
2019/08/15 18:41:19 pixelToClip: 50 x 0 => -0.843506 x 1.000000
2019/08/15 18:41:19 pixelToClip: 0 x 50 => -1.000000 x 0.791232
```

This is the full source code for the app:

```
$ cat a.go
// # recipe for running a.go (Go 1.11 or higher)
// mkdir tmp                                    ;# create dir for module
// cp a.go tmp                                  ;# put app in dir
// cd tmp                                       ;# enter dir
// go mod init tmp                              ;# init module
// go get -u github.com/udhos/basgo@mainthread  ;# get lib from branch mainthread
// go run a.go                                  ;# run

package main

import (
        "github.com/faiface/mainthread"
        "github.com/udhos/basgo/baslib"
)

func main() {
        mainthread.Run(run)
}

func run() {
        mainthread.Call(func() {
                baslib.G = baslib.InitWin(640, 480)
        })
        baslib.Cls()
        baslib.Screen(9)
        baslib.Color(7, 5)
        baslib.Line(0, 0, 639, 479, -1, -1) // Line 1 (only linux)
        baslib.Line(50, 0, 0, 50, -1, -1)   // Line 2 (linux + windows)
        baslib.Print(baslib.InputCount(1))  // wait keyboard
        baslib.Println(``)
        baslib.Cls()
        baslib.Color(2, -1)
        for i := 50; i <= 300; i++ {
                baslib.Line(100, 50, 319, i, -1, -1)
        }
        baslib.Color(4, -1)
        baslib.LineBox(10, 100, 40, 130, 1, -1, false)
        baslib.LineBox(15, 105, 35, 125, -1, -1, true)
        baslib.LineBox(80, 130, 50, 100, 1, -1, false)
        baslib.LineBox(75, 125, 55, 105, -1, -1, true)
        baslib.LineBox(40, 140, 10, 170, 1, -1, false)
        baslib.LineBox(15, 165, 35, 145, -1, -1, true)
        baslib.LineBox(50, 170, 80, 140, 1, -1, false)
        baslib.LineBox(55, 165, 75, 145, -1, -1, true)
        baslib.Print(baslib.InputCount(1)) // wait keyboard
        baslib.Println(``)
}
```

Function baslib.Line() is the main portion responsible for the draw, and it is available here:

https://github.com/udhos/basgo/blob/mainthread/baslib/graphics.go#L269

Comment: Looks like logs are same, before consider bugs of OpenGL, can you check once more about your code? Or Provide them? Error can also happen in global variables.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble working out the control flow since you seem to be using Goroutines and calling functions on the main thread. Are the two lines drawn by separate calls to draw()? Is this in response to a GLFW window repaint event?
In the past I've found that OpenGL calls only work reliably when made from the main thread, and on MS Windows drawing only works when inside a PAINT event handler. On Linux I've found drawing stuff at random times usually works, but not on MS Win.

Comment: @FrankWang I have added the runnable source code for the app into the question.

Comment: @HughFisher Yes, before running OpenGL call on the main thread, the code did not work at Windows at all. Yes, the two lines are drawn by separate calls to draw(), you can see how Line() is called from the runnable app source code I have just included in the question. The issue on Windows might actually be due to calls happening outside a PAINT event. I am thinking on how to check it. Thanks for the directions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think the problem is simpler than I first thought: you are calling window.SwapBuffers() each time you draw a line, when you really should just be calling it once at the end of a frame.

A buffer swap on a modern system means "show the current contents of the framebuffer on the display and give me a new offscreen buffer to draw on". Whether or not this new offscreen buffer is blank or not isn't defined, since the OpenGL standard is to call glClear anyway. A quick C test on my dual boot laptop **does** have different behaviour for Linux and MS Windows.

So your program draws the first line, swaps the buffers, draws the second line, swaps the buffers again. It looks to me as if the Linux implementation is preserving the frame buffer contents, so your first line is still there when the second line is drawn. On MS Windows I guess that the new frame buffer is cleared, so the first line is "displayed" very very briefly and then overwritten by the second frame buffer with only the second line.

Comment: You spotted the issue! Thank you very much! I put a SwapBuffer() before and another after the draw call to confirm it, and it worked. Sorry to abuse, but is there an way to work with glfw with a single buffer, or emulate single buffer? Maybe a way to copy data from the backbuffer to the front buffer instead of swapping them. I don't need a rendering loop and avoiding one would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Well, "swap" these days CAN mean copy from back to front, which is probably what your Linux version does. Between GPUs and compositing window managers it's almost impossible to do single buffered drawing today. (And single buffer has problems with tearing and flickering which double buffering was introduced to solve.)
Think of SwapBuffers() as just marking the end of a frame, the equivalent of a transaction commit  or web page submit. All graphics systems, heck even printers, need some kind of "that's a complete image" indicator.

Comment: Thank you for directions. Issue is, the app would be a lot simpler if it could issue incremental draw commands to a single buffer, since it does not actually benefit from the advantages of issuing full scene draw commands then swapping buffers in a rendering loop.